# Moved code from overleaf to local latexmx, how to debug?

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, debugging

I have files that I moved from overleaf, which is set to be very permissive. And better, to have "tex" support whenever I needed it.

I compiled using:

```
latexmk -pdf -pv 01_Analyzing_Complexity.tex
```

then switched to:

```
pdflatex 01_Analyzing_Complexity.tex
```

no difference there.

The error originally showed undefined control sequence with \hline
which isn't much clue as their are hlines all over the tables, but
I moved the first hline to the line before and saw that was the one. So here is the relevant code.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{How Functions Grow Asymptotically (Polynomials)}
    As $n$ grows, $n^2$ is obviously a lot worse. And $n^3$ is even worse \\
    Try to find algorithms that are as low as possible on the complexity scale \\
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|m{5em}|m{5em}|m{5em}|}
      \hline
      $n$    & $n^2$  & $n^3$        \\ \hline
      $1$    & $1$    & $1$          \\ \hline
      $10$   & $100$  & $1000$       \\ \hline
      $100$  & $10^4$ & $10^6$       \\ \hline
      $1000$ & $10^6$ & $10^9$       \\ \hline
      $10^6$ & $10^{12}$ & $10^{18}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

I got rid of fragile as it wasn't necessary, but that's not the issue.

Comment: Is page 14 (by page number, not frame number) a fragile frame with some kind of table?

Comment: As a first debugging step, take `latexmk` out of it and compile directly with e.g. `pdflatex`. I don't think this will help much in this case, but it is often easier to simplify the compilation process as much as possible.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it is a fragile frame with a lstlisting. How do you see that?

Comment: @Dov The `[13     ]` tells you that the 13th page was finished and the file ending `.vrb` is used for fragile frames. This should allow you to narrow down the error to a MWE.

Comment: Is there no way to see what line number the problem is being triggered by? This is slides, so there are more pages than usual. But having to look at an entire page of instructions seems crazy. Even if the compiler is off, a starting point would be useful.

Comment: @Dov Please don't post code fragments. Always make a small test document including a class and the necessary packages so we can see if you e.g. load the necessary packages.

Comment: (unrelated, but you should not abuse \\ for line breaks outside of tables). Also the `\centering` is unnecessary.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks, that was done for me, and I didn't know what I could remove, there are also slides where text is aligned for \quad repeatedly. I will slowly edit it away. For now I just want it to compile without errors